# spliting based on a condition and Array arguments to IF are of different size

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, code-splitting

I'm working on a sheet that can be extracted from a system and all the data is in one cell so i need to split them and it is basic for all cells except for resutls. as you can see test results should follow the same pattren of result status. so i regularlly splited one column (test status) and i tried to split test results based on if condition

it worked perfectly, however, for some status test results were not spliting because (Array arguments to IF are of different size.)

how do i fix this, please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Because `IF()` function is checking only first cell of `C2:G2` range. Concat them into a single string them use search function to detect word `Final`. Try-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Final",JOIN(",",C2:G2))),SPLIT(H2,","),"")
```

Comment: This gives arrange of a regular split column for test reseult, what i want is to split test reselt in the same order of test status.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
=BYCOL(C2:G2,LAMBDA(Σ,(IF(Σ<>"Final",,INDEX(SPLIT(H2,","),, COUNTIF(C2:Σ,Σ))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked. But would please explain the code to me. Like what does Σ do and why did you use two ,, in the code ?

Comment: Σ is just a name identifier I've given to the range section C2:G2 here. I've created a breakup scenario of how the formula works stepwise here (https://i.imgur.com/d1DIrR5.png). the split parts would conveniently land in the 1 and 2 cells respectively.